# Make pagesections fill browserheight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get pagesection to fill the browserheight. I´ve tried to apply a 100 height to all elements, but it´s not working. It works good if I set a heigh: 100vh, but It´s not the way I want to take, so I wonder what Im doing wrong?

Site: Svenssonsbild.se/Konsthandel Second and third menu are anchorlinks to the spagesections.

Comment: 100vh is the easiest way to do this by far.

Comment: JavaScript is your best solution. Get the height of the users screen, set elements to fill that height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `height:100%` means 100% of the height of the parent element so you need to specify the height of the parent for it to work.

If you want to set your element to 100% of the height of the browser, you need to make sure **all the parent** elements up to the `<body>` tag have a percent height.

Comment: I didn´t want to use the 100vh beacuse I wanted a deeper broswersupport. Anyhow, i worked out with 100% height on all elements, turned out I had plugin that prevented me from this. Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the element's CSS height to 100vh is the intended way to do exactly what you're trying to do. `100vh` specifies that the element should always be the full height of the viewport, so unless you've got some other requirement that you haven't described, that's what you should be doing -- you'll need to explain why "that's not the way I want to take" if there's more to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your content it might be a good idea to set the `min-height` property instead of the `height` property since the content might need more space than the available viewport size offers. Or you can just evaluate the section's height and compare it to the viewport height. Using jQuery the following might work:

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var height = ($(this).height() > $(window).height()) ? $(this).height() : $(window).height();
    $(this).css('height', height + 'px');
});
```

You might need to adjust the selector to fit your needs.